# Angular not getting logged in user details

Tags: node.js, angular, service, jwt

I'm new to Angular and am trying to pass user data to a client app built in angular using a service. I have checked and logged in success from results using postman from the back-end built in Node, Express, MongoDb + jwt for authentication. The problem is that the angular method for checking authentication is simple thus should show changes, which doesn't do so.

Here's the sample code:

```
authStatus() {
    const status = `/api/auth`;
    // to infinity and beyond.. But first...
    this.http.get(this.url + status).subscribe((data) => {
      if(data instanceof Object) {
        console.log(data);
        // data should return logged In user email, id and name
        // actual(Angular Client) data returned is the err caught of { "err" : true, "msg": "Login to continue"}
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What error in console it showing. Your question is not clear.

Comment: You are not passing email and password, as I can see. First please check is it a Post or Get API? And then pass the email/username and password in the request so that back-end can verify it. But as I can see, you have not passed anything.

Comment: Yes the method is for auth. I have already registered and logged in the user correctly. I am trying to check the authentication status of the user using jwt from the server.

Comment: With JWT you do not need to check the status as every time you will do a new API request you will pass the token (received when you logged in) to the API that automatically will check if it is still valid (= user is logged in) and then return the data accordingly.

Comment: Yes Thanks, @Ferie. the backend is passing the data successfully through postman but when it comes to checking it on angular app component, no changes are detected even after logging in.

Comment: What changes are you referring to? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Heres the basic outline: 1 register. 2 login 3 Check auth 4 route to profile component. so far all is working except to point to check auth. It keeps finding the user as not logged in as stated in the comments.